# ffmpeg claims that I gave it no output file

Tags: ffmpeg, freebsd, lame

I want to use ffmpeg to to ffmpeggy things on my freeBSD box, but recently I ran into a problem.  I have never used ffmpeg, so I started by just copying and pasting stuff off of websites, but it never works.  I typed:

```
ffmpeg -i foo.mp4 -f mp3 foo.mp3
```

It just says:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> ? (?))
Encoder (codec mp3) not found for output stream #0:0
```

You can view the whole thing it printed out here.  foo.mp3 was just a blank file.  Does anybody have any advice on this?

Comment: Next time asking about ffmpeg command line questions, please 1) post them on [SU] where they're on topic and 2) include the full uncut command line output. I voted to migrate this question, so you don't have to re-post.

Answer (score 0):

The hint it gave you was

```
Encoder (codec mp3) not found for output stream #0:0
```

Try reinstalling ffmpeg from ports with LAME support.

```
cd /usr/ports/multimedia/ffmpeg
make config
# enable LAME here; it's disabled by default
make reinstall clean
```

Comment: I would, but I'm not root, so I can't.  Is there any alternative to trying to convince my sysadmin to do this?

Comment: @Accidentalbrine Download a static build from here: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html — then just run that instead.

Comment: How should I go about building it?  While I've tried, I've never been able to build something from source.

Comment: @Accidentalbrine You don't have to build it, you just download a **static build**, which is an executable file. Go to the download page, and click the link where it says "static builds", which points to http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/ right now.

Comment: @slhck The static Linux build won't work in FreeBSD unless Linux compatibility is enabled, and I think that only supports 32-bit executables. The other choice would be to set up a FreeBSD installation in something like Virtualbox, build and install the port (but statically linking it), then move the executable over to the other machine.

Comment: I didn't see the FreeBSD tag, my bad.